# Using Castle.Windsor to register an interceptor for only the derived class, not the base class

Tags: castle-windsor, castle, castle-dynamicproxy

I am working on upgrading our project from .Net 2 to .Net4.5, at the same time I'm pushing as many references as I can to NuGet and making sure the versions are current.

I am having a problem getting one of the tests to run

The Test Classes:

```
        public class Person
    {
        public static int PersonBaseMethodHitCount { get; set; }
        public virtual void BaseMethod()
        {
            PersonBaseMethodHitCount = PersonBaseMethodHitCount + 1;
        }
        public static int PersonSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount { get; set; }
        public virtual void SomeMethodToBeOverridden()
        {
            PersonSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount = PersonSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount + 1;
        }
    }

    public class Employee : Person
    {
        public static int EmployeeSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount { get; set; }
        public override void SomeMethodToBeOverridden()
        {
            EmployeeSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount = EmployeeSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount + 1;
        }
        public static int EmployeeCannotInterceptHitCount { get; set; }
        public void CannotIntercept()
        {
            EmployeeCannotInterceptHitCount = EmployeeCannotInterceptHitCount + 1;
        }

        public virtual void MethodWithParameter(
            [SuppressMessage("a", "b"), InheritedAttribute, Noninherited]string foo)
        {
        }
    }

    public class MyInterceptor : IInterceptor
    {
        public static int HitCount { get; set; }
        public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
        {
            HitCount = HitCount + 1;
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
    }
```

The test (there is no setup for this fixture):

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<MyInterceptor>().ImplementedBy<MyInterceptor>());
        container.Register(
            Component
            .For<Employee>()
            .ImplementedBy<Employee>()
            .Interceptors(InterceptorReference.ForType<MyInterceptor>())
            .SelectedWith(new DerivedClassMethodsInterceptorSelector()).Anywhere);
        container.Register(Classes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).Pick().WithService.FirstInterface());

        var employee = container.Resolve<Employee>();
        Person.PersonBaseMethodHitCount = 0;
        Person.PersonSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount = 0;
        Employee.EmployeeCannotInterceptHitCount = 0;
        Employee.EmployeeSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount = 0;
        MyInterceptor.HitCount = 0;
        employee.BaseMethod();
        Assert.That(Person.PersonBaseMethodHitCount, Is.EqualTo(1));
        // The BaseMethod was not overridden in the derived class so the interceptor should not have been called.
        Assert.That(MyInterceptor.HitCount, Is.EqualTo(0));

        Person.PersonBaseMethodHitCount = 0;
        Person.PersonSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount = 0;
        Employee.EmployeeCannotInterceptHitCount = 0;
        Employee.EmployeeSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount = 0;
        MyInterceptor.HitCount = 0;
        employee.SomeMethodToBeOverridden();
        Assert.That(Person.PersonSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount, Is.EqualTo(0));
        Assert.That(Employee.EmployeeSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(MyInterceptor.HitCount, Is.EqualTo(1)); //The test errors out on this line

        Person.PersonBaseMethodHitCount = 0;
        Person.PersonSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount = 0;
        Employee.EmployeeCannotInterceptHitCount = 0;
        Employee.EmployeeSomeMethodToBeOverriddenHitCount = 0;
        MyInterceptor.HitCount = 0;
        employee.CannotIntercept();
        Assert.That(Employee.EmployeeCannotInterceptHitCount, Is.EqualTo(1));
        Assert.That(MyInterceptor.HitCount, Is.EqualTo(0));
```

I added a comment to denote where the test fails.

So far as I can tell the problem is arising  in the DerivedClassMethodsInterceptorSelector

Selector:

```
public class DerivedClassMethodsInterceptorSelector : IInterceptorSelector
{
    public IInterceptor[] SelectInterceptors(Type type, MethodInfo method, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
    {
        return method.DeclaringType != type ? new IInterceptor[0] : interceptors;
    }
}
```

When it makes the comparison of types, the type variable is System.RuntimeType but should be Employee (at least this is my understanding).

**EDIT:** 
This problem was occurring using Castle.Windsor and Castle.Core 3.2.1, After making NuGet install the 3.1.0 package the code works as expected.

I am leaning towards this being a bug, but I could also just be a change in the logic.

Comment: I replicated this exact behaviour.

Comment: What proxies are used? If used? Work with Windsor 3 years ago, but as it remember most of such problems was with dynamic proxies (windsor+proxies+nhibernate sometimes cause braincrash). Best way is to investigate System.RuntimeType in debugger more closer - it's ancestors, attributes and even name can give you info to make decision

Comment: The only proxies that are used, are the ones Windsor creates automatically when registering with interceptors, when debugging there is absolutely no information on the System.RuntimeType. After a brief look in the source GetType is called on the target before calling the interceptor selector and in this case it appears that the target was already a Type object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the same issue with version 3.3.3 with this simple unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyUnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void BasicCase()
    {

        var ProxyFactory = new ProxyGenerator();
        var aopFilters = new IInterceptor[] {new TracingInterceptor()};
        var ConcreteType = typeof(MyChild);

        var options = new ProxyGenerationOptions { Selector = new AopSelector() };

        var proxy = ProxyFactory.CreateClassProxy(ConcreteType, options, aopFilters) as MyChild;
        proxy.DoIt();

    }
}

public class AopSelector : IInterceptorSelector
{
    public IInterceptor[] SelectInterceptors(Type runtimeType, MethodInfo method, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(runtimeType == typeof(MyChild));

        return interceptors;
    }
}

public class MyWay
{
    public virtual void DoIt()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}
public class MyChild : MyWay
{
    public virtual void DoIt2()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(200);
    }
}

public class TracingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var isProperty = invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("get_")
                      || invocation.Method.Name.StartsWith("set_");

        if (isProperty)
        {
            invocation.Proceed();
            return;
        }

        LogMethod(invocation);
    }

    protected virtual void LogMethod(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var target = (invocation.InvocationTarget ?? invocation.Proxy).GetType().Name;
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        try
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
            invocation.Proceed();
        }
        finally
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            var result = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

I fixed it by changing Castle's source code and editing method `TypeUtil.GetTypeOrNull` to look like this:

```
public static Type GetTypeOrNull(object target)
{
    if (target == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var type = target as Type;
    if (type != null)
    {
        return type;
    }

    return target.GetType();
}
```

Of course this is a naive fix, because the problem is somewhere else and it is that instead of an object instance passed to this method, its `Type` is passed in. However checking if the passed parameter is of type `Type` and if so returning it instead of calling `GetType` on it makes it work.

Comment: Thanks David,  I had traced th issue to the same code block you mention, though I didn't know the issue was as generic as you've boiled it down to.  I have submitted an issue on Castle's issue tracker for this: https://github.com/castleproject/Core/issues/74